# How to extract an original table from a join in sql

Tags: mysql

[with this database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kj3ca.png) I did the next query :

```
WITH comp_courses AS 
(SELECT * FROM course WHERE title LIKE "Comp%") 
SELECT * FROM (instructor INNER JOIN (comp_courses INNER JOIN teaches USING(course_id)) USING(ID));
```

now that returns a join of a bunch of tables. But what I want is only the colmuns from that query that appear in instructor. Any ideas on how to do it?

Comment: in the second query, instead of *, you can write `instructor.column_name` for all the columns which you want. or you can alias (for example inst) instructor and then instead of * in the second select statement, use `inst.column_name`.

Comment: 'A select list consisting only of a single unqualified * can be used as shorthand to select all columns from all tables:' - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html

Answer (score 0):

All you would have to do is select all the columns from that table using the `*` operator like so:

```
instructor.*
```

This should get you the result your looking for:

```
SELECT 
  instructor.* 
FROM 
  instructor AS `i` 
  JOIN teaches AS `t` ON `t`.id = `c`.id 
  JOIN course AS `c` ON `c`.course_id = `t`.course_id
WHERE 
  `c`.title LIKE 'Comp%';
```

Hope this helps,